# Trying to generate a button-group with Bootsrap and AngularJS to redirect to different URLs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, controller

I am trying to create a button group of two (using bootstrap and angularjs) that, when clicking on them, each would redirect to a different URL. I currently have the following code (copied only the relevant pieces):

```js
app.controller('LinkController',function(link, $scope, $location){
    $scope.go = function(){
 $location.url(link); 
    };
});
```

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" data-ng-controller = "LinkController">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click = "go('test1.html')">Click1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click = "go('test2.html')">Click2</button>
</div>
```

However, this doesn't work, and I am not sure why. I might not be passing the arguments correctly, but I tried it even without passing the link itself and it still didn't work. Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much of Angular js, but there are other alternative ways to achieve the same purpose. This works with simple html

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
<a href="test1.html"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Click1</input></a>

<a href="test2.html"><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Click2</input></a>
</div>
```

Notice I changed the button element to input, this because a button element can not be placed inside an anchor tag `<a>`.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The above solution will just generate simple links and would not generate the same nice looking buttons I have now.

Comment: An input cannot be placed inside an <a> either.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to pass the url ?, 
if so, then i would be like this :

```js
app.controller('LinkController',function(link, $scope, $location){
    $scope.go = function(link){
 $location.url(link); 
    };
});
```

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" data-ng-controller = "LinkController">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click = "go('test1.html')">Click1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click = "go('test2.html')">Click2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after many many attempts, and with some inspiration from the answers above, I was able to solve it in the following way:

```js
app.controller('LinkController',function($scope){
  $scope.go = function(link){
 window.location = link; 
  };
   
});
```

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" data-ng-controller = "LinkController">
   <button id = Image type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
      data-ng-click = "go('Test1.html')">Click1</button>
   <button id = Text type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
      data-ng-click = "go('Test2.html')">Click2</button>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help guys.